# Memory efficient ways of merging a vector with a large data.table to perform calculations (R)

Tags: r, performance, merge, data.table, memory-efficient

I have a dataset with year-based data predicted by multiple models, in data.table format.

```
library(data.table)
nYears = 20 # real data: 110
nMod   = 3  # real data: ~ 100
nGrp   = 45

dataset <- data.table(
  group_code = rep(seq(1:nGrp   ),    times= 3*nYears ),
  Year       = rep(seq(1:nYears ),   each=nGrp   ),
  value      = rnorm(2700      , mean = 10, sd = 2),
  var1       = rep (rnorm(nGrp  , mean = nMod, sd = 1) ,  times= nMod*nYears ),
  var2       = rep (rnorm(nGrp  , mean = 1.5, sd = 0.5) , times= nMod*nYears ),
  model   = as.character(rep(seq( from = 1, to = nMod ) ,  each=nGrp  *nYears ))
)
setkey(dataset, Year, model)
```

I need to perform a set of calculations from this *dataset* based on a vector, named *x*, of lenght=1001 and consists on a `seq(-2, 8, by=0.01)`.
To do so, I created a new data.table (*dt*) with repeated versions of *dataset* to merge vector *x*, accordingly:

```
dt  <- dataset[, lapply(.SD, function(x) rep(x, 1001))]
dt[, x :=  rep(round(seq(-2, 8, by=0.01), 2), each= nYears*nGrp*nMod) ]
```

Since my original *dataset* includes hundreds of models, this operation is not memory efficient.

The most important operation I need, includes the generation of normal distribution of x, with mean = var1 and sd= var2, by group_code, Year and model. For example:

```
 # key computation
 dt [, norm_dist := dnorm (x, var1, var2) , by= .(group_code,  Year, model )]
```

This last operation is quite fast in my desktop. However, I have other operations to perform that require to subset the data.table and are highly RAM consuming. An example:

```
dt[ x %between% c( 2, 5.99), dt2 := rep_len( rev(dt [x %between% c(-2, 1.99)]$value), length.out=.N) , by= .(Year, model) ]
```

The following error pop-s up:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.3 Gb
```

I believe the problem in this specific step is related to the subset and the rev() function.

Nevertheless, the approach I'm using to performing the set of calculations based on the vector "*x*" from data.table dt, does not seem appropriate since the moment I merged the dataset with the vector I need for calculations ("*x*").

I was hoping someone could teach me how to efficiently improve my code, since I have a considerable amount of models in the original dataset, greatly increasing its size.

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way you can demonstrate the intended outcome with a data.table that doesn't contain millions of rows? I started losing track of things after the second `rep_len`s multiplying the first `rep_len`s.

Comment: dear @r2evans i did some edits that make my question more clear. thnks!

Comment: Thank you. My hope for reducing the problem-set and asking for the *"intended outcome"* was that perhaps somebody could recommend a more efficient way to come to the same results.

Comment: You can do `dt2 := rep_len(rev(dt[condition, value), length.out = .N)` which would slightly help memory allocation. I am unsure of your data range, but if all of your data points span -2 to 6 you could also do the logical comparison before subsetting e.g. `ind = x < 2; dt[ind == T, dt2 := rep_len(rev(dt[!ind, value]), length.out = .N), by =...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this part of code should be clearer

```
dt[ x %between% c( 2, 5.99), dt2 := rep_len( rev(dt [x %between% c(-2, 1.99)]$value), length.out=.N) , by= .(Year, model) ]
```

as it is a bit like a black box to me. Especially because this double subsetting is where your problem is generated.

These bits of code, `x %between% c( 2, 5.99)` and `dt[x %between% c(-2, 1.99)]`, should result always to the same positions in all your cases. You should consider that in your code to make it more efficient.

Try something like this to make things a bit clearer:

```
by_YM <- split(dt, by=c("Year", "model"))
ind1  <- which(by_YM[[1]][["x"]] %between% c( 2, 5.99))
ind2  <- which(by_YM[[1]][["x"]] %between% c(-2, 1.99))

for(i in 1:length(by_YM)){
 
  dt_i <- by_YM[[i]]
  #val1 <- rep_len(rev(dt_i$value[ind2]), length.out=length(ind1)) #val1 is equal to val, no need for rep_len
  val  <- rev(dt_i$value[ind2])
  
  by_YM[[i]] <- dt_i[ind1, dt2 := val] 
  
}
```

however ours dt2 columns are not equal but as I am not sure of how the final result should be I cannot debug it.

```
dt2_a <- dt[Year == 20 & model == 3, dt2]
dt2_b <- by_YM[["20.3"]][, dt2]

test  <- cbind(dt2_a, dt2_b)
```

The second code is also much faster.

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark( "new_code" = {
  by_YM <- split(dt, by=c("Year", "model"))

ind1  <- which(by_YM[[1]][["x"]] %between% c( 2, 5.99))
ind2  <- which(by_YM[[1]][["x"]] %between% c(-2, 1.99))

for(i in 1:length(by_YM)){
  
  dt_i <- by_YM[[i]]
  val1 <- rep_len(rev(dt_i$value[ind2]), length.out=length(ind1)) #val1 is equal to val, no need for rep_len
  val  <- rev(dt_i$value[ind2])
  
  by_YM[[i]] <- dt_i[ind1, dt2 := val] 
  
}}, "old_code" = dt[ x %between% c( 2, 5.99), 
                   dt2 := rep_len( rev(dt [x %between% c(-2, 1.99)]$value), length.out=.N) , by= .(Year, model) ],  
times = 5)

Unit: milliseconds
     expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
 new_code  155.426  156.4916  200.6587  185.0347  188.9436  317.3977     5  a 
 old_code 1290.909 1299.8570 1398.6866 1370.4526 1471.0569 1561.1574     5   b
```

Give it a try and good luck